# How to create an excel worksheet throught a shell script?

Tags: html, excel, scripting, ksh, worksheet

I'm trying to create a shell script that creates an output file with html content & xml content but my goal is open this file as an excel workbook/file (xls format).

This is a part of the code:

```
Log INF "Creating the first excel file: ${FICHERO_OUT}"

echo "<html>" >> ${DIR_OUT}/${FICHERO_OUT}
   echo "<style>

   .table_main {
              border: 1px solid black;
              border-top-style: ridge;
              border-bottom-style: ridge;
              border-left-style: ridge;
              border-right-style: ridge;
              border-color: black;
              }          

        </style>" >> ${DIR_OUT}/${FICHERO_OUT}
   echo "   <body>" >> ${DIR_OUT}/${FICHERO_OUT}
   echo '<table>' >> ${DIR_OUT}/${FICHERO_OUT}
   echo '<th class="table_main" bgcolor="##FFBF00">ERROR</th>' >> ${DIR_OUT}/${FICHERO_OUT}
   echo '<th class="table_main" bgcolor="##FFBF00" >DESCRIPTION</th>' >> ${DIR_OUT}/${FICHERO_OUT}


      echo "<tr>" >>  ${DIR_OUT}/${FICHERO_OUT}
      echo "<td>0</td>" >> ${DIR_OUT}/${FICHERO_OUT}
      echo "<td>DES</td>" >> ${DIR_OUT}/${FICHERO_OUT}
      echo "</tr>" >>  ${DIR_OUT}/${FICHERO_OUT}

      echo '</table>' >>  ${DIR_OUT}/${FICHERO_OUT}
    echo "   </body>" >> ${DIR_OUT}/${FICHERO_OUT}
    echo "</html>" >>  ${DIR_OUT}/${FICHERO_OUT}`
```

This part of the code works fine, but when I try to modify the Worksheet name, I can't. I try to do it with the next code:

```
echo "<?xml version="1.0"?>" >>  ${DIR_OUT}/${FICHERO_OUT}
echo "<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"" >>  ${DIR_OUT}/${FICHERO_OUT}
echo "xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"" >>  ${DIR_OUT}/${FICHERO_OUT}
echo "xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"" >>  ${DIR_OUT}/${FICHERO_OUT}
echo "xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"" >>  ${DIR_OUT}/${FICHERO_OUT}
echo "xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">" >>  ${DIR_OUT}/${FICHERO_OUT}
echo "<Worksheet ss:Name="Student Data">" >>  ${DIR_OUT}/${FICHERO_OUT}
echo "<table>" >>  ${DIR_OUT}/${FICHERO_OUT}
....
```

I wrote here the HTML code I mentioned before.

```
....
echo "</table>" >>  ${DIR_OUT}/${FICHERO_OUT}
echo "</Worksheet>" >>  ${DIR_OUT}/${FICHERO_OUT}
echo "</Workbook>" >>  ${DIR_OUT}/${FICHERO_OUT}
```

Please, could someone help here? Any suggestion to modify the worksheet name? Any alternative?

Comment: I suggest you use  Perl  or java  which have dedicated modules to create Excel instead of shell script.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to open the file with Excel, generate a `.csv` file.
When you start the `.csv` file with a line `SEP=x`, the character `x` will be used between fields.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I've solved it. I did it, using only xml code and adding "sqlplus querys + spool".

Thank you very much for your support.

Best Regards,